# linking Google AdWords account to Google Analytics account

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, links, google-ads

I have a Google Analytics account that has two profiles, one for www.ayrshireminis.com and one for www.crmpicco.co.uk. I have a Google AdWords account that I would like to link to my Google Analytics account, but for some reason the Google AdWords admin is telling me I cannot do that.

Within the AdWords admin and the My Account > Linked Accounts > Google Analytics section both profiles show as `Not Available`

... it also has this message...

> None of your profiles are available for linking due to your account
>   settings.

How can I link these two accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across a how to on this on the Google support site for AdWords - http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1704341

There is a video that explains it perfectly.